# Anova in R: Dataframe selection

Tags: r, data-structures, anova

I just run into a problem when using a variable in the anova term. Normally I would use "AGE" directly in the term, but run it all in a loop so myvar will change.

```
myvar=as.name("AGE")
x=summary( aov (dat ~  contrasts*myvar)+ Error(ID/(contrasts)), data =set))
names(set) = "contrasts" "AGE" "ID" "dat"
```

It's like when I want to select:

```
 set$myvar
```

- not function! but `set$AGE` yes

Is there any code for this?

Comment: Well done for providing a reproducible example.

Answer (score 4):

You need to create a string representation of the model formula, then convert it using `as.formula`.

```
myvar <- "AGE"
f <- as.formula(paste("dat ~", myvar))
aov(f)
```

Comment: Thank dat is also a part of the dataframe, how should I the use this??    f <- as.formula(paste("dat ~ contrasts*myvar"))

Answer (score 1):

As Richie wrote, pasting seems like the simplest solution. Here's a more complete example:

```
myvar <- "AGE"
f <- as.formula(paste("dat ~ contrasts *", myvar, "+ Error(ID/contrasts)"))
x <- summary( aov(f, data=set) )
```

...and instead of `set$myvar` you would write

```
set[[myvar]]
```

A more advanced answer is that a formula is actually a call to the "~" operator. You can  modify the call directly, which would be slightly more efficient inside the loop:

```
> f <- dat ~ contrasts * PLACEHOLDER + Error(ID/contrasts) # outside loop
> f[[3]][[2]][[3]] <- as.name(myvar) # inside loop
> f # see what it looks like...
dat ~ contrasts * AGE + Error(ID/contrasts)
```

The magic [[3]][[2]][[3]] specifies the part of the formula you want to replace. The formula actually looks something like this (a parse tree):

```
`~`(dat, `+`(`*`(contrasts, PLACEHOLDER), Error(`/`(ID, contrasts))
```

Play around with indexing the formula and you'll understand:

```
> f[[3]] 
contrasts * AGE + Error(ID/contrasts) 
> f[[3]][[2]] 
contrasts * AGE
```

**UPDATE:** What are the benefits of this? Well, it is more robust - especially if you don't control the data's column names. If `myvar <- "AGE GROUP"` the current paste solution doesn't work. And if `myvar <- "file.create('~/OWNED')"`, you have a serious security risk...

Comment: Cute use of `~`, though I'm not entirely convinced that it's more readable.

Comment: @richie: No, not more readable but more robust. See updated edit.